# How to discard part of function output in python?

Tags: python, output

Suppose I have a function in python which returns a pair (text, rc). In some cases I want to use both parts of the pair but in some cases I want to use only one of them. In python, is there a similar syntax to the following one

```
text, rc = f() # read both, text and rc
text, ~ = = f() # read only text
~, rc = = f() # read only rc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common Python idiom is to use `_` as a dummy variable:

```
text,rc = f()
text,_ = f()
_,rc = f()
```

Or you can just use:

```
text,rc = f()
text = f()[0]
rc = f()[1]
```

You can even use multiple _'s:

```
_,_,_,x = method_returning_4_args_and_only_want_the_last()
```